# Add specific user's to be able to view text channel with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make it so that a new channel can be created with a command in a category called alliances, where specific users can be added to the channel. Can't work out how to add the users to the channel by name.
Can anyone help? **My code so far:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def channelCreate(ctx, channel_name, member: discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="Alliances")
    await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, category=category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) you can use `overwrites` parameter to create a secret channel. You have to use [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with target [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20channel#discord.Member) or [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20channel#discord.Role) and [PermissionOverwrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20channel#discord.PermissionOverwrite) as a value.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def channelCreate(ctx, channel_name, member : discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }

    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="Alliances")
    await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```